# Adwords API Cost Per Click from a Gclid

Tags: google-ads-api

I am really would like to be able to pull out the cost of a click from adwords with a gclid. I can upload this to adwords but we have rich meta data about the customer after they have completed our online application, I would like to be able to do some analysis on this data, but need to find out the cost of the customer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, Google do not release the cost information at that granular level. They do provide a click performance report (details [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/click-performance-report)) but performance metrics such as cost, conversion, etc. are all infuriatingly absent.

You can, of course, match the gclId to a unique criteriaId, device, date, etc. then get the cost for that combination but, at least in general, you'll lose a little information in the aggregation unless there happens to be just a single click in that segment.

Comment: This is silly, I am sure that other people must have much larger amounts of data that they would need to analyse.

Comment: No argument here :-)